# Make sure generated number does not exist and pick another one if it does

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have following insert query in our SQL Server database:

```
INSERT INTO voertuig (voertuig_nummer, kenteken)
SELECT 
ISNULL((SELECT MAX(v.voertuig_nummer) FROM voertuig v), 0) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY te.Kenteken) AS voertuig_nummer,
te.Kenteken
FROM #TempExcelData te
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM voertuig v WHERE v.kenteken = te.Kenteken
)
```

`voertuig_nummer` is our primary key. For each insert (26 rows at the moment) we want to make sure it does not exist and if it does we want it to take another one. How do we accomplish this in SQL Server?

Comment: Why not use a built in feature for this, like an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`? Your solution can, and will, result in race conditions.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to make sure that there are no repeated rows with the same information even if there are going to be such rows in the future? If that's the case then you can do that by making your table have a ID column and making it an IDENTITY(1, 1) column. That way it will have a number that will auto increment every insert.

Comment: That query, like all attempts to use MAX+1 *guarantees* duplicates and bad relations if eg some rows are deleted. It will also result it very bad performance as it blocks the entire table, preventing any other concurrent modification operation

Comment: we can't do that at the moment, i have to make a workaround for 2 years until the migration and deletion of our old system is real, and then we can go to identity

Comment: @LaurensWolf you can't do what you try to do at any moment. The very idea is flawed. `MAX+N` will always generate duplicate numbers if one of the last N rows is deleted. The `MAX` operation always locks either the entire table or the index. If the value is used in related tables, you'll end up with related rows pointing to the wrong record

Comment: Why can't you even use a `SEQUENCE`?

Comment: There are loads of duplicate questions like this out there

Comment: A `SEQUENCE` is a separate database object. You don't have to modify the exiting table to use it. You can write `INSERT INTO MyTable(ID,License) SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SomeSequence, License FROM temp_Licenses`

Comment: If we disregard concurrency issues, what's wrong with the code you're currently using? if you take the max and then append row_number, you are guaranteed not to have duplicates, so what's your real question